# How to write the condition to check the validation using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

hello friends,

```
        $('input[name=checkedRecordsCat]').attr('checked', true);
        $('input[name=checkedRecordsSubCat]').attr('checked', true);
        $('input[name=checkedRecordsAtta]').attr('checked', true);
        $('input[name=checkedRecordsTextComp]').attr('checked', true);
        $('input[name=checkedRecordsVariableText]').attr('checked', true);
        $('input[name=checkedRecordsFreeFormText]').attr('checked', true);
```

I have this in my page. i need to check if non of them are checked I need to show a popup message. atleast one check box checked I need do return true.

how to write this condition using jquery or javascript

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming there are no other elements that have a name starting with `checkedRecords` you can use the [starts-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) combined with the [`:checked` selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

```
if ( $('input[name^="checkedRecords"]:checked').length ){
   // at least one is checked
   return true;
} else {
   // none is checked
   // show popup here..
}
```

Comment: You could also use `$('input[name^="checkedRecords"]').is(':checked');`

Comment: @zzzzBov +1, perfectly valid, and possibly more readable than the version i posted..